# DataType for exposing data as json in mvc model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

how can I introduce new property into my mvc model which will hold this cities json data.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   MyModel model = repository.GetById(id);
   if (model.CountryId.HasValue)
   {
       // load cities into new property
   }    
   return this.View(result);
}
```

what data type should be my property (Cities) if I want to be exposed as json on client side for further js manipulation? ICollection? Is there any recommendation for this?

Comment: You can't send Json data in 'return View()'. You can bind your data to you model property and at the View you can get it as `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MyProperty))` ;

Answer (score 1):

Set them up as any object type you like:

```
MyModel model = repository.GetById(id);
if (model.CountryId.HasValue)
{
   model.Cities = repository.GetCities(model.CountryId.Value);
}    
return this.View(model);
```

Then, on the client, you can use Json.NET library to serialize it.  I use this trick when I'm trying to pass an array to a client-side JS component; essentially, it serializes the array of objects into a client-side array:

```
@(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Cities))
```

Whatever type of object represents each city is what determines what gets rendered out to the client; it simply reads the object and renders an equivalent JS object with all the same properties.  You can fine tune that by saying:

```
Model.Cities.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.Name, .. })
```

Which only includes a subset.  There are also attributes you can use to exclude certain columns I believe.

Comment: so I can use IEnumerable or ICollection as datatype to populate on server side as long as I convert cities on client side?

Comment: Well, IEnumerable<T> or ICollection<T> where T has to be defined in a way that can be serialized.  Otherwise, use the anonymous object technique I mentioned. It's up to the serialize to control how it gets serialized, which I use Json.NET.